# Different result to what expected when using overflow: scroll

Tags: html, css

This [page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) states *"browsers always display scrollbars whether or not any content is actually clipped."*

1. This isn't the case for #2.
2. #1 does display a scroll-bar but only when I scroll. For some reason I was led to believe it'd always be there.

I am using Chrome. Is this behavior normal? Have I misinterpreted MDN?

```css
div {
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 5px solid red;
    overflow: scroll;
}

section {
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 5px solid red;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>1</h1>
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Praesentium modi beatae explicabo officiis voluptatibus doloribus quae ipsam, voluptate reiciendis iure maiores repudiandae, hic quaerat eaque amet alias ducimus voluptas consequatur!</div>
  <h1>2</h1>
  <section>Voluptate reiciendis iure maiores repudiandae, hic quaerat eaque amet alias ducimus voluptas consequatur!</section>
</body>
```

[see it here youtube](https://youtu.be/K-1xBUNvCsc)

Comment: What is the browser you are using when you checked this?

Comment: Working perfectly fine in chrome...

Comment: @yazantahhan Chrome

Comment: you have a lot of extension installed, check them or try with a fresh chrome installation

Answer (score 0):

When an `overflow` is on `scroll` *browsers will always display scrollbars whether or not any content is actually clipped* that's it when `overflow` is set to `scroll` so if you want the contents not to show scrollbars when contents is not overflowing you can simply use `auto` on overflow like

> `overflow: auto;`

```css
div {
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 5px solid red;
    overflow: auto;
}

section {
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 5px solid red;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>1</h1>
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Praesentium modi beatae explicabo officiis voluptatibus doloribus quae ipsam, voluptate reiciendis iure maiores repudiandae, hic quaerat eaque amet alias ducimus voluptas consequatur!</div>
  <h1>2</h1>
  <section>Voluptate reiciendis iure maiores repudiandae, hic quaerat eaque amet alias ducimus voluptas consequatur!</section>
</body>
```

so if you want to have the scrollbar on one dimension you could just use `overflow-y` to have scrollbars on the y-axis or use `overflow-x` to have the scrollbar on the x-axis
the following is an example of overflow on one dimension

### Example

```css
div {
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 5px solid red;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

section {
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 5px solid red;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>1</h1>
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Praesentium modi beatae explicabo officiis voluptatibus doloribus quae ipsam, voluptate reiciendis iure maiores repudiandae, hic quaerat eaque amet alias ducimus voluptas consequatur!</div>
  <h1>2</h1>
  <section>Voluptate reiciendis iure maiores repudiandae, hic quaerat eaque amet alias ducimus voluptas consequatur!</section>
</body>
```

Comment: have you answered my question?

Comment: What kind of an answer are you seeking for?

Comment: I've added a video to the bottom of my question. Both element's have `auto: scroll` - is the following expected behaviour: #1's scroll-bar only shows when it's being scrolled #2's scroll-bar never shows

Comment: @tonitone120 maybe it's your browser problem check for an update of reset all of the settings

Comment: so can I confirm it is different to yours? What setting should I reset?

Comment: [Try this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VTLHxboMivM)

Comment: Solution no.4 on this article has solved problem 2. As for problem 1: is a box that has no over-flow and has `overflow: scroll` supposed to show a scroll-bar? https://www.guidingtech.com/fix-scroll-bar-not-showing-chrome/#:~:text=As%20with%20many%20other%20Chrome,in%20the%20address%20bar%20directly.&text=Scroll%20to%20the%20bottom%20to,hardware%20acceleration%20when%20available%20option.

Comment: Can I ask one last thing - does a box that has no over-flow but has `overflow: scroll` still show a scroll-bar (for you)?